# Connection to private proxy socks5 with "chrome.webRequest.onAuthRequired" and "webRequestAuthProvider" permission

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a Chrome extension to connect to a private proxy server. In version 3 of the manifest, the webRequestAuthProvider permission was added to provide a username and password for authorization. I am sure that my code should work, but it does not work, but the connection is made to the open servers.

My current code
Please help me figure out why the connection to the private server is not happening

My manifest v3

```
{
  "name": "Proxy",
  "version": "1.0",
  "minimum_chrome_version": "22.0.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "description": "Proxy",
  "permissions": [
    "proxy",
    "tabs",
    "unlimitedStorage",
    "storage",
    "webRequest",
    "webRequestAuthProvider"
  ],
  "host_permissions": [
    "<all_urls>"
  ],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "js/background.js"
  },
  "action": {
    "default_title": "Proxy",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  }
}
```

my background.js file

```
var config = {
        mode: "fixed_servers",
        rules: {
        singleProxy: {
            scheme: "socks5",
            host: host,
            port: parseInt(port)
        }
        }
    };
function setProxy(){ //on click
chrome.proxy.settings.set({value: config, scope: "regular"}, function () {
    console.log("Connection established");
  });
}
function callbackFn(details) {
    return {
        authCredentials: {
            username: username,
            password: password
        }
    };
}

chrome.webRequest.onAuthRequired.addListener(
            callbackFn,
            {urls: ["<all_urls>"]},
            ['asyncBlocking']
);

function clearProxy() { // on click
  chrome.proxy.settings.clear({ scope: "regular" }, function () {
    console.log("Disconnected");
  });
}
```

Comment: When you're using `asyncBlocking`, I believe you get a second parameter to `callbackFn` which you can use to provide a response. Have you tried that to see if it works any better?

Comment: @OliverDunk @ Oliver Dunk thaks for you answer. Are you talking about "function callbackFn(**details**)"? I'm a beginner and don't quite understand a lot of simple things

Comment: Yeah, I would try something like this:

function callbackFn(details, callback) {
    callback({authCredentials: {
            username: username,
            password: password
        }
    });
}

Comment: @OliverDunk I already have a callback function, I described it above, I call it inside the chrome.webRequest.onAuthRequired event:
function callbackFn(details) {
  return {
      authCredentials: {
          username: username,
          password: password
      }
  };
}

chrome.webRequest.onAuthRequired.addListener(
          callbackFn,
          {urls: ["<all_urls>"]},
          ['asyncBlocking']
);

Comment: I understand, but you're currently returning the credentials from this function. Could you instead try having your `callbackFn` take a second argument? Chrome should pass you a function which you can then call with your response object.

Comment: @OliverDunk I have reread all your messages and tried to understand them. I tried to do this and it still didn't work out:
function callbackFn(details, callback) {
  const response = {
    authCredentials: {
      username: username,
      password: password
    }
  };

  callback(response);
}

chrome.webRequest.onAuthRequired.addListener(
  callbackFn,
  { urls: ["<all_urls>"] },
  ["asyncBlocking"]
);
Oliver, did I understand you correctly? Still difficult for me.

Comment: Hmm, that looks like it should work. Could you try testing https://jigsaw.w3.org/HTTP/Basic/ which has username "guest" and password "guest"? That will identify if it is a problem with the code or the particular server you're connecting to.

Comment: @OliverDunk Thanks for answers! I went to the page from 3 different ip addresses that work great on android and ios vpn applications both under real credentials and under "guest" "guest" and as a result the site gave me the inscription - "ERR_SOCKS_CONNECTION_FAILED". But, when I went to the site under my own IP address, the result is "Your browser made it!". I can assume that it's in the code, since IP addresses are already used in applications for mobile devices and PC. Still does not work in general

Comment: Hmm, could you elaborate on what you tried? Have you tried updating your extension to provide "guest" and "guest" and then navigating to that website? Does "Your browser made it!" show in that case?

Comment: @OliverDunk when i updated my extension to provide "guest" and "guest" and navigated to that website the page not loading

Comment: and also in bworser console tool > network there is no requests

Comment: @OliverDunk I guess if the Authorization header is not present, it means that the authentication credentials were not sent by the callbackFn function

Comment: Ah, ok! If the page is not loading that's a good sign - it means you're never calling the callback you were given as the second parameter. Can you try going back to the change I suggested a few messages ago and see if it works then?

Comment: @OliverDunk If you're talking about this code:  function callbackFn(details, callback) {
  const response = {
    authCredentials: { username: username, password: password },
  };
  callback(response);
}
chrome.webRequest.onAuthRequired.addListener(
  callbackFn,
  { urls: ["<all_urls>"] },
  ["asyncBlocking"]
);
it does not work

Comment: Unfortunately this is working on my end so it's hard to know what to try next. Are you sure you have host permissions for the test domain? If so, would you be comfortable sharing a small test extension on GitHub so I can see the full extension?

Comment: Thanks! I just cloned the code, removed the call to `chrome.proxy.settings.set`, and changed the username and password to "guest". I went to https://jigsaw.w3.org/HTTP/Basic/ and was signed in automatically. Unfortunately I'm not sure that Stack Overflow is the best place to continue troubleshooting - if you want to email me (my address is on my website, linked in my profile) I'm happy to continue discussing there.

Comment: @OliverDunk I wrote you on your address, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, socks5 authentication is not currently implemented in Chrome, and there are no plans to support it. For more details, see https://crbug.com/1309413.

It's worth noting that socks5 authentication is sent in plain text, which means it may be undesirable. You may want to consider using an HTTP(s) proxy instead. These are supported by the onAuthRequired API and provide some additional flexibility in terms of security.